Problem calculating symmetrized product of Ricci tensor
I was reading the following article, about an example of neckpinching for Ricci flow on $S^{n+1}$, with $n \geq 2$, but I have a problem in the proof of Proposition 5.7. The setting is the following.
Identify the punctured sphere $S^{n+1}$, i.e. the sphere without the north and south poles, with $(-1,1)\times S^n(1)$, and let's consider on it metrics of the form $g = \varphi(x)^2dx^2 + \psi(x)^2 \hat g$, where $x$ is the coordinate on $(-1,1)$ and $\hat g$ is the canonical metric on the unit sphere $S^n(1)$.
With the change of coordinates given by $s(x) = \int_0^x\varphi(x)dx$ the metrics can be rewritten as $g = ds^2+\psi^2 \hat g$. Thanks to the theory about warped products, it's not difficult to deduce that the sectional curvatures of the $2$-planes perpendicular and tangential to the spheres $\{x\} \times S^n$ are, respectively, $K_0 = -\frac{\psi_{ss}}{\psi}$ and $K_1 = \frac{1-\psi_s^2}{\psi^2}$. The Ricci tensor is given by $Rc = nK_0ds^2 + [K_0 + (n-1)K_1]\psi^2 \hat g$.
Define $F = (K_1-K_0)[(n-1)ds^2 + \psi^2 \hat g]$, which is a symmetric $(0,2)$-tensor, and $F * Rc$ the symmetrized product given by $(F * Rc)_{ij} = F_i^kRc_{kj} + Rc_i^kF_{kj}$.
I want to prove that the Ricci tensor satisfies $\partial_tRc=\Delta Rc+F*Rc$.
Thanks to the well known equation for the evolution of Ricci tensor $\partial_tRc_{ij} = \Delta R_{ij} + \underbrace{2Rm_{ipjq}Rc^{pq} - 2Rc_i^pRc_{pj}}_{:=T_{ij}}$ it is sufficient to prove that $(F * Rc)_{ij} = T_{ij}$.
Around a point $(x,P) \in (-1,1) \times S^n$ we choose coordinates $\{y^1,\ldots,y^n\}$ near $P$ in which $\hat g_{\alpha\beta} = \delta_{\alpha\beta}$ at $P$. Setting $y^0 = s$ we obtain a coordinate system near $(x,P)$. If Roman indices belong to $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ and Greek indices belong to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, in these coordinates the only non-vanishing components are: $g_{00} = 1$, $g_{\alpha\alpha}=\psi^2$, $Rm_{\alpha0\alpha0} = \psi^2K_0$, $Rm_{\alpha\beta\alpha\beta} = \psi^4K_1$ (with $\beta\neq\alpha$), $Rc_{00} = nK_0$ and $Rc_{\alpha\alpha} = \psi^2[K_0+(n-1)K_1]$.
In these coordinates I am able to prove that $(F * Rc)_{ij} = 0 = T_{ij}$ if $i\neq j$ and $(F * Rc)_{00} = T_{00}$. I am done if I can prove $(F * Rc)_{\alpha\alpha} = T_{\alpha\alpha}$. But this is where my problem starts. Infact:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(F * Rc)_{\alpha\alpha} & = F_\alpha^jRc_{j\alpha} + Rc_\alpha^jF_{j\alpha}
  &\qquad\qquad T_{\alpha\alpha} & =2Rm_{\alpha p\alpha q}Rc^{pq}-2Rc^p_\alpha Rc_{p\alpha} \\
  & = F_\alpha^\alpha Rc_{\alpha\alpha}+Rc_\alpha^\alpha F_{\alpha\alpha}
  & & =2Rm_{\alpha0\alpha0} Rc^{00}+2Rm_{\alpha\beta\alpha\beta}Rc^{\beta\beta}\\
    & =g^{\alpha s}F_{\alpha s}Rc_{\alpha\alpha}+g^{\alpha s}Rc_{\alpha s}F_{\alpha\alpha} & & \:\:\:\:\:-2Rc^\alpha_\alpha Rc_{\alpha\alpha} \\
  & =g^{\alpha\alpha}F_{\alpha\alpha}Rc_{\alpha\alpha}+g^{\alpha\alpha}Rc_{\alpha\alpha}F_{\alpha\alpha} & & =2n\psi^2K_0^2+2(n-1)\psi^4K_1\frac{1}{\psi^4}\psi^2[K_0+(n-1)K_1]\\&=2\psi^2(K_1-K_0)[K_0+(n-1)K_1] & & \:\:\:\:\:-2\frac{1}{\psi^2}\psi^4[K_0+(n-1)K_1]^2\\& & & =2(n-1)\psi^2K_0(K_0-K_1)
\end{alignat*}
These two quantities are equal if and only if $nK_0 + (n-1)K_1 = 0$. Is that even true? Have I made any calculation mistake? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
